# Magento SQL Insert query is not working and shows no errors

Tags: database, mysql, sql

I am building a simple PHP file to query Magento to get all orders and order items to insert into an external Database.

I am able to query Magento and get the rercrods I need.

When I try to connect to 3rd party DB and insert, it simply fails on first insert but gives now error or feedback at all!

When I run `print_r($external_db_write);` I can see that my external 3rd part DB username and password and DB name are all returned in the result of that so I believe the DB connection is setup correctly which is set in some XML config file.

Below are the PHP and SQL that I am trying to run on each order record to insert into my own DB.

I just cannot figure out why it is not creating the record and is not showing any messages or anything either!

Any help extremely appreciated I am on verge of getting fired over this, thanks

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

//load the magento app with the admin store
require_once('../../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// Insert Order data into NAM App DB
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$external_db_write = $resource->getConnection('externaldb_write');

$orderQuery = "insert into `neonandmore_timeclock`.`nam_orders` (
            `order_id` ,
            `order_number` ,
            `order_type` ,
            `customer_id` ,
            `sugarcrm_qms_id` ,
            `date_created` ,
            `date_modified` ,
            `order_status` ,
            `total_item_count` ,
            `order_shipping_price` ,
            `order_tax_price` ,
            `order_items_price` ,
            `order_grand_total_price` ,
            `order_shipping_tracking` ,
            `order_shipping_ship_date` ,
            `order_notes`,
            `billing_address_firstname`,
            `billing_address_lastname`,
            `billing_address_telephone`,
            `billing_address_email`,
            `billing_address_street`,
            `billing_address_city`,
            `billing_address_region`,
            `billing_address_postcode`,
            `billing_address_country_id`,
            `shipping_address_firstname`,
            `shipping_address_lastname`,
            `shipping_address_telephone`,
            `shipping_address_email`,
            `shipping_address_street`,
            `shipping_address_city`,
            `shipping_address_region`,
            `shipping_address_postcode`,
            `shipping_address_country_id`,
             )
             VALUES (:order_id, :order_number, :order_type, :customer_id, :sugarcrm_qms_id, :date_created, :date_modified, :order_status, :total_item_count, :order_shipping_price, :order_tax_price, :order_items_price, :order_grand_total_price, :order_shipping_tracking, :order_shipping_ship_date, :order_notes, :billing_address_firstname, :billing_address_lastname, :billing_address_telephone, :billing_address_email, :billing_address_street, :billing_address_city, :billing_address_region, :billing_address_postcode, :billing_address_country_id, :shipping_address_firstname, :shipping_address_lastname, :shipping_address_telephone, :shipping_address_email, :shipping_address_street, :shipping_address_city, :shipping_address_region, :shipping_address_postcode, :shipping_address_country_id)";

// insert into 3rd part DB
$external_db_write->query($orderQuery, $orderBinds);
```

The data being passed to the query looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [order_id] => 5761
    [order_number] => 100005363
    [order_type] => RUSH
    [customer_id] => 4355
    [sugarcrm_qms_id] => 1
    [date_created] => 2015-08-03 20:03:40
    [date_modified] => 2015-08-18 20:32:29
    [order_status] => 19
    [total_item_count] => 1
    [order_shipping_price] => 0.0000
    [order_tax_price] => 0.0000
    [order_items_price] => null
    [order_grand_total_price] => 464.0000
    [order_shipping_tracking] => null
    [order_shipping_ship_date] => 2015-08-11
    [order_notes] => null
    [billing_address_firstname] => John
    [billing_address_lastname] => Doe
    [billing_address_telephone] => 645-666-6666
    [billing_address_email] => jghjn@123.com
    [billing_address_street] => 123 Street
    [billing_address_city] => Austin
    [billing_address_region] => Texas
    [billing_address_postcode] => 78701
    [billing_address_country_id] => US
    [shipping_address_firstname] => John
    [shipping_address_lastname] => Doe
    [shipping_address_telephone] => 512-223-3257
    [shipping_address_email] => thomas123@123.com
    [shipping_address_street] => 1212 Rio Grande
    [shipping_address_city] => Austin
    [shipping_address_region] => Texas
    [shipping_address_postcode] => 78701
    [shipping_address_country_id] => US
)
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to get SQL logging to work and I get this entry...

Unfortunately it isn't much help since my date has no issue in it.

Where it says `2015-` that is for the field `[date_created]`
, any ideas?

```
## 2015-08-24 20:22:32
EXCEPTION 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
                     VALUES ('5761', '100005363', 'RUSH', '4355', '1', '2015-' at line 36' in /var/www/vhosts/neonandmore.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/neonandmore.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/neonandmore.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/neonandmore.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/neonandmore.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/neonandmore.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('insert into `ne...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/neonandmore.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(420): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('insert into `ne...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/neonandmore.com/order-report/export-orders/magento-order-export123.php(413): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('insert into `ne...', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/neonandmore.com/order-report/export-orders/magento-order-export123.php(106): exportOrdersAndOrderItems('glassbendingadv...')
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma spare in your `$orderQuery` just before the closing `)`:

```
 ...
 `shipping_address_country_id`,
 )
 VALUES (:order_id, :order_number, ....
```

Than one comma needs to be removed:

```
$orderQuery = "insert into `neonandmore_timeclock`.`nam_orders` (
            `order_id` ,
            `order_number` ,
            `order_type` ,
            `customer_id` ,
            `sugarcrm_qms_id` ,
            `date_created` ,
            `date_modified` ,
            `order_status` ,
            `total_item_count` ,
            `order_shipping_price` ,
            `order_tax_price` ,
            `order_items_price` ,
            `order_grand_total_price` ,
            `order_shipping_tracking` ,
            `order_shipping_ship_date` ,
            `order_notes`,
            `billing_address_firstname`,
            `billing_address_lastname`,
            `billing_address_telephone`,
            `billing_address_email`,
            `billing_address_street`,
            `billing_address_city`,
            `billing_address_region`,
            `billing_address_postcode`,
            `billing_address_country_id`,
            `shipping_address_firstname`,
            `shipping_address_lastname`,
            `shipping_address_telephone`,
            `shipping_address_email`,
            `shipping_address_street`,
            `shipping_address_city`,
            `shipping_address_region`,
            `shipping_address_postcode`,
            `shipping_address_country_id`
             )
             VALUES (:order_id, :order_number, :order_type, :customer_id, :sugarcrm_qms_id, :date_created, :date_modified, :order_status, :total_item_count, :order_shipping_price, :order_tax_price, :order_items_price, :order_grand_total_price, :order_shipping_tracking, :order_shipping_ship_date, :order_notes, :billing_address_firstname, :billing_address_lastname, :billing_address_telephone, :billing_address_email, :billing_address_street, :billing_address_city, :billing_address_region, :billing_address_postcode, :billing_address_country_id, :shipping_address_firstname, :shipping_address_lastname, :shipping_address_telephone, :shipping_address_email, :shipping_address_street, :shipping_address_city, :shipping_address_region, :shipping_address_postcode, :shipping_address_country_id)";
```

Comment: thanks this helped with that particular error.  I guess I was thinking that last comma was allowed for some reason, maybe because it is in JS